# Ruby on Rails Join Table Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a Ruby on Rails application setup like so:

User Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
```

Role Model

```
has_many :transactions
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Transaction Model

```
belongs_to :role
```

This means that a join table is used called `roles_users` and it also means that a user can only see the transactions that have been assigned to them through roles, usage example:

```
user = User.find(1)
transactions = user.roles.first.transactions
```

This will return the transactions which are associated with the first role assigned to the user.  If a user has 2 roles assigned to them, at the moment to get the transactions associated with the second role I would do:

```
transactions = user.roles.last.transactions
```

I am basically trying to figure out a way to setup an association so I can grab the user's transactions via something like this based on the roles defined in the association between the user and roles:

```
user = User.find(1)
transactions = user.transactions
```

I am not sure if this is possible?  I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to execute separate SQL queries to find transactions for each role, you can first get role_ids for the user, and then find all transactions with these role ids with single query:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  def transactions
    Transaction.scoped(:conditions => {:role_id => role_ids})
  end
end
```

`Transaction.scoped` is used here so you can add more conditions when necessary, like

```
user.transactions.all(:limit => 10, :conditions => [ ... ])
```

Comment: Voyta's answer is better than mine. Also, see this blog post for more information on using `scoped`: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-has-finder-functionality

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method to `User` to [collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003127) the transactions for each of the user's roles into an Array of Arrays and then [flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002218) this into a single Array:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def transactions
    user.roles.collect { |role| role.transactions }.flatten
  end
end
```