# Ruby on Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I am starting to create my sites in Ruby on Rails these days instead of PHP.

I have picked up the language easily but still not 100% confident with associations :)

I have this situation:

**User Model**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
```

**Roles Model**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

**Journal Model**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
```

So I have a `roles_users` table and a `journals_roles` table

I can access the user roles like so:

```
user = User.find(1)
User.roles
```

This gives me the roles assigned to the user, I can then access the journal model like so:

```
journals = user.roles.first.journals
```

This gets me the journals associated with the user based on the roles.  I want to be able to access the journals like so `user.journals`

In my user model I have tried this:

```
def journals
  self.roles.collect { |role| role.journals }.flatten
end
```

This gets me the journals in a flatten array but unfortunately I am unable to access anything associated with journals in this case, e.g in the journals model it has:

```
has_many :items
```

When I try to access `user.journals.items` it does not work as it is a flatten array which I am trying to access the has_many association.

Is it possible to get the `user.journals` another way other than the way I have shown above with the collect method?

Hope you guys understand what I mean, if not let me know and ill try to explain it better.

Cheers

Eef

Comment: Probably that's not links to your question, but i want to aware you that the rails team recommends to use has_many :through  instead of has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: :) thanks for the advice, any is appreciated at the moment :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `user.journals` you should write query by hand. As far as I know Rails does `has_many :through` associations (habtm is a kind of `has_many :through`) one level deep.   You can use `has_many` with `finder_sql`.

`user.journals.items` in your example doesn't work, becouse `journals` is an array and it doesn't have `items` method associated. So, you need to select one journal and then call `items`:

```
user.journals.first.items
```

I would also modify your `journals` method:

```
def journals
  self.roles(:include => :journals).collect { |role| role.journals }.flatten.uniq
end
```

`uniq` removes duplicates and `:inlcude => :journals` should improve sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802539/ruby-on-rails-join-table-associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802539/ruby-on-rails-join-table-associations/2803120#2803120)

You can use `Journal.scoped` to create scope with conditions you need. As you have many-to-many association for journals-roles, you need to access joining table either with separate query or with inner select:

```
  def journals
    Journal.scoped(:conditions => ["journals.id in (Select journal_id from journals_roles where role_id in (?))", role_ids])
  end
```

Then you can use `user.journals.all(:include => :items)` etc